# Overriding Symfony2 delete form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I've been breaking my head for hours now trying to find a way to achieve this: how can I override the Symfony2 delete form?

When I call the delete form in my Twig like this:

```
{{ form(delete_form }}
```

It actually renders:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <div id="form">
        <div>
             <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">
                 Delete
             </button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="...">
    </div>
</form>
```

Ok. I can change the "Delete" context with my Entity Controller and add some classes. Good.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <div id="form">
        <div>
             <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">
                 <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
             </button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="...">
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I want to add HTML instead of the delete, let's for instance the [Font Awesome trash icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/trash/). How can I do that? The actual HTML would hence be:

I read [Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field) but I still can't find a way to do that. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this in your Twig Template
and dont add the submit button via formbuilder!

```
{{ form_start(delete_form) }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
{{ form_end(delete_form) }}
```

Comment: Actually, it almost works. Now I have the wished button with the trash icon. However, the delete button (the one with the "Delete" text) is still here. So I have two buttons instead of one!

Comment: Just remove submit field from class where you define this form. It field should look like $builder->add('delete, 'submit', array())

Comment: That's not a good practice to remove submit buttons from the form builder, especially if you have several submit buttons that acts differently. You can't use `$form->get('button_name')->isClicked();` from your controller, for example. You might want to [overwrite your form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) instead.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo yes I actually want to do that. My question comes down to how to overwrite my theme to allow adding HTML in my buttons for the Font Awesome icon.

Comment: Fairy easy: 1) in your view, use `{% form_theme yourFormVar 'YourBundle:ViewDir:your-theme.html.twig' %}`, 2) in the "your-theme.html.twig" create blocks named "YourType_label", "YourType_errors" and "YourType_widget" to do whatever you want. You can see a sample in one of my projects [here](https://github.com/ninsuo/twigfiddle/blob/master/web/src/Fuz/AppBundle/Resources/views/Fiddle/templates-theme.html.twig)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo Could you explain that a little more in an answer? I can't seem to get it working.